# Describe geometrically sets of the following form

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to describe geometrically sets of the form:

$\{z\in\mathbb{C} : Az \bar z +Bz + \bar B\bar z + C=0\}$,

$A,C\in\mathbb{R}, B\in\mathbb{C}$ .

Check also for $A=0$.

(I have a feeling that it is supposed to describe circles in the complex plane, but I don't have the knowledge to check it nor prove it)

Question posed by the professor for home exercise, on hyperbolic geometry on the complex upper half plane model course.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? If $A=0$ the LHS should remind you of a basic property, otherwise you can assume WLOG that $A=1$ and try to group the terms in $z, \bar z$ into a more familiar expression.

Comment: I am extremely surprised that a student studying **hyperbolic geometry** in $\mathbb C$ of all things, would not even think to try the most basic technique of substituting $z = x + yi$ and proceed from there.  Were I the professor, I would suspect that such a student lacks the prerequisite knowledge to take such a course.

Comment: I do actually lack the prerequisite knowledge

Comment: @NikolaosKokkalis Alt. hints: if $A=0$ then $Bz+ \overline{\,Bz\,}+C = 0$, otherwise if $A=1$ then $z \bar z+ B z + \bar B \bar z \color{red}{+B \bar B - B\bar B}+C=0$.